# Reading json:api filters with fast api

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to move my rest api project from flask to FastAPI
on my get function I made it very easy to get all the filters and by using flask I used the command

```
filter_value = request.args.get(f'filter[{filter_name}]')
```

where `filter_name` changed between all the fields i have on my object and that's how i could read urls like

[http://127.0.0.1:8000/beers?filter[isbn]=72533](http://127.0.0.1:8000/beers?filter%5Bisbn%5D=72533)

but now when I moved to fast api I can't find a way to read url like this.

Answer (score 1):

Naming parameters in such a way, in my opinion, is not good.

Despite that, here's a working example.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def get(req: Request):
    if "filter[filter]" in req.query_params: 
        return req.query_params["filter[filter]"]

    return ""
```

You have to directly access the request and manipulate it, since it is not possible to declare it as a function's parameter due to it's name. Choosing a different naming convention would allow to define the parameter as in the example below

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def get(my_parameter=None):
    if my_parameter is not None: 
        return my_parameter

    return ""
```

Comment: It worked!
thanks!

And yes, it's not that good but I'm just trying to learn new methods and less focused on the concept of making it easy to run

Comment: @yuvalhayun if this answer helped you, please, mark it as useful and solving your problem

Comment: Whether or not it's a good idea to name parameters this way, that's what's defined in the JSON:API specifications. I've run into this same issue with FastAPI. Thanks for the answer.